# How to call sub web recursively?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom, user-controls

I`m making a treeview to show Site levels.

When I try to retrieve sub webs, it returned only 1 subwebs.

So I searched google, and they told me use recursion.

But I`m not good at it, please somebody help me how to use it

My code is below

```
 private void BindTreeView()
    {
        TreeNode parentNode = null;

        string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;
        //site level
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        {
            parentNode = new TreeNode();
            parentNode.Text = site.Url;
            parentNode.NavigateUrl = site.Url;

            //web level
            foreach (SPWeb web in site.RootWeb.Webs)
            {
                TreeNode rootwebNode = new TreeNode();

                rootwebNode.Text = web.Title;
                rootwebNode.NavigateUrl = web.Url;
                parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(rootwebNode);

                //list level
                foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
                {
                    if (!list.Hidden)
                    {
                        TreeNode listNode = new TreeNode();
                        listNode.Text = list.Title;
                        listNode.NavigateUrl = list.DefaultViewUrl;
                        rootwebNode.ChildNodes.Add(listNode);
                    }
                }

                //subweb level
                foreach (SPWeb subweb in web.Webs)
                {
                    //Maybe Recursion is here.....
                    TreeNode subwebNode = new TreeNode();
                    subwebNode.Text = subweb.Title;
                    subwebNode.NavigateUrl = subweb.Url;
                    rootwebNode.ChildNodes.Add(subwebNode);
                    try
                    {
                        //subweb`s list
                        foreach (SPList swbList in subweb.Lists)
                        {
                            if (!swbList.Hidden)
                            {
                                TreeNode swListNode = new TreeNode();
                                swListNode.Text = swbList.Title;
                                subwebNode.ChildNodes.Add(swListNode);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (subweb != null)
                        {
                            subweb.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            trvSiteTree.Nodes.Add(parentNode);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as below:

```
private static void BindWebData(TreeNode node, SPWeb currentWeb)
{
    if (currentWeb.Webs == null || currentWeb.Webs.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (SPWeb web in currentWeb.Webs)
    {
        TreeNode currentNode = new TreeNode();

        currentNode.Text = web.Title;
        currentNode.NavigateUrl = web.Url;
        node.ChildNodes.Add(currentNode);

        //list level
        foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
        {
            if (!list.Hidden)
            {
                TreeNode listNode = new TreeNode();
                listNode.Text = list.Title;
                listNode.NavigateUrl = list.DefaultViewUrl;
                currentNode.ChildNodes.Add(listNode);
            }
        }

        //recusively iterate over all child webs for current web
        //and bind as child to current web node
        BindWebData(currentNode, web);
    }
}

private static void BindTreeView()
{
    TreeNode parentNode = null;

    //site level
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://sp2013dev/sites/dev"))
    {
        parentNode = new TreeNode();
        parentNode.Text = site.Url;
        parentNode.NavigateUrl = site.Url;

        BindWebData(parentNode, site.RootWeb);


        trvSiteTree.Nodes.Add(parentNode);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Don't forget about disposing and exception handling, I removed for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you Sergei Sergeev! Your code is right and correct! Also I think I quite understand how to work it!! :)